# Interactions.py: How do I receive user from UserSelectMenu?

Tags: python, discord

I'm new to discord bots and dealing with Discord API. I've been learning by going through and playing with the interactions.py library. Currently confused as to how I'm supposed to extract a selected user from the UserSelectMenu.

Current function:

```
async def add_booster_pack_to_user(self, ctx: SlashContext, pack_name: str):
    user_menu = UserSelectMenu(
        custom_id="user_select",
        placeholder="Select a user",
        min_values=1,
        max_values=1,
    )
    interaction = await self.bot.wait_for_component("Select a user to add the booster pack to.", components=user_menu)
    user_id = interaction.data.get("values")
```

I've tried playing with.data and message attributes, but I don't understand how to get information from a component besides using a @listen to see when a component is interacted with.

Comment: I don't know exactly how the library works but try to get the callback and then the value of the callback? This should tell you what the user chose/clicked.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution after reading through some code of other bots that use interactions.py.

You can access a value by having a variable equal the message (don't know if that's totally right) that has the bot wait for the component, then you access the value by ctx.values[x]. I'm assuming if you allow more than one choice, that they will be held in the values array.

```
 async def add_booster_pack_to_user(self, ctx: SlashContext, pack_name: str):
  user_menu = UserSelectMenu(
      custom_id="user_select",
      placeholder="Select a user",
      min_values=1,
      max_values=1,
  )
  await ctx.send("Select a user to add the booster pack to.", components=user_menu)
  selection = await self.bot.wait_for_component(components=user_menu)
  user_id = int(selection.ctx.values[0])
```